# PercentRelativeLayout, how to set the height programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout, android-percent-library

I am using PercentRelativeLayout from android percent support package. this is what I have in my layout.

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/view_parent"
    app:layout_heightPercent="68%" android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/mountain_meadow" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <View android:id="@+id/view_child" android:layout_width="match_parent" app:layout_heightPercent="30%"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

I want to change the height of `view_child` programmatically. How can I do that using `PercentRelativeLayout.LayoutParams` or any other way.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Do you want to set a new percentage value? If yes, you need to:

```
View view = findViewById(R.id.view_child);
PercentRelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (PercentRelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
// This will currently return null, if it was not constructed from XML.
PercentLayoutHelper.PercentLayoutInfo info = params.getPercentLayoutInfo();
info.heightPercent = 0.60f;
view.requestLayout();
```

Comment: How set another value without percent? for example, marginBottom in dp, using Percent layout params?

Comment: hi @gruszczy, Do you know why I am always getting PercentLayoutInfo as 'null' ? Please help me.

Comment: Hi @gruszczy, as per your comment '// This will currently return null, if it was not constructed from XML.'. Please help me adding this in XML